# force Office 2016 add-in to use Edge instaed of IE

Tags: office-js, microsoft-edge, office-addins, word-addins, office-2016

I read that:

Beginning with Office 365 version 16.0.11629 and Windows 10 version 1903, Office Add-ins running on Office 365 for Windows will use a Microsoft Edge WebView as the runtime.

We are running Office 2016 on Windows 10 version 1803 - but Edge is our default browser. Is there a way we can force our add-ins to use Edge instead of Internet Explorer?

Our plugin performs much better on Edge then IE, as half of the features do not work on IE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't force Office 2016 add-in to use Edge or IE. Which browser is used depends on:

- The computer's operating system.
- Whether the add-in is running in Office on the web, Microsoft 365, or non-subscription Office 2013 or later.

For the detailed information, you can refer to the table in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins). I think you can only update the OS version to force Edge usage in add-in or change your code to make it compatible with IE.

Comment: Whats about Windows Server 2016 (Terminal) it loads IE instead of Edge?!
(newest Office Version & tried to install webview 2)